# Why does ConfigurationFile return appname.exe.Config with capital 'C'?

Tags: c#, config

I have the below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pathToConfig = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;

    Console.WriteLine($"path to the config file: {pathToConfig}");

    Console.Read();
}
```

And 2 PCs:

PC_1: Windows 10 + Visual Studio Express 2010
PC_2: Windows 10 + Visual Studio CE 2017

I compiled and ran the code on both machines. I got the following results:

1. Application compiled on PC_1 outputs the same result on both machines:

   ```
   C:\pathToTheFile\appname.exe.config
   ```
2. Application compiled on PC_2 outputs the same path (Config with capital 'C') on both machines:

   ```
   C:\pathToTheFile\appname.exe.Config
   ```

The change of the version of .Net does not make any difference.

Can someone explain please?

Thank you.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE].

Comment: I edited my initial post and tried to be more specific.